# What happens if a pointer returned by a function is not stored?

Tags: c++

There's a function which returns a pointer(any type), if I don't store the pointer when I call the function, what happens?
Will the function still return a pointer in this case? If yes, then will there be a memory leak because I'm not freeing up the allocated memory?

Consider the below code as an example:

```
int * testfunc()
{
int * a=new int();
return(a);
}

int main()
{
testfunc();
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Yes it's lost and leads to memory leak.

Comment: Adding brackets on return statements is a bad practice, particularly so in conjunction with `decltype(auto)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There absolutely will be a memory leak. You need to balance all calls to `new` with a `delete` on the returned pointer.

C++ gives you some class to help you manage that `delete`: see `std::unique_ptr`. Essentially the *destructor* of `std::unique_ptr` calls `delete` which, more often than not, is extremely useful.

Comment: And when it's not useful, you call `release()`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to manually free every block of memory allocated with `new`, `new[]`, `malloc()` and `calloc()`. The method will still return a pointer and it's pointing to valid memory but you can't use or free it. In C++ you should nearly always return by value and [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics) will take care of dynamic memory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does leak memory.

The pointer variable in function scope will get destroyed when the function exit, but the data the pointer has allocated will remain in memory.
The function return the address of where the data is located.

If this is really what your function is intended to do, then you can still delete the data with the returned address

```
int *pi = testfunc();
delete pi;
```

Then there won't be a memory leak when your program exit, but yes there is a memory leak in the function as you have asked.

Answer (score -3):

I ran valgrind on the code given in the question(after compiling it with '-g' option) using the statement`(valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --track-origins=yes ./test)`
Below is the output

```
==59142== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==59142== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==59142== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==59142== Command: ./test
==59142==
==59142==
==59142== HEAP SUMMARY:
==59142==     in use at exit: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==59142==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 4 bytes allocated
==59142==
==59142== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==59142==    at 0x4A075BC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==59142==    by 0x4006D3: testfunc() (test.cpp:7)
==59142==    by 0x4006EF: main (test.cpp:13)
==59142==
==59142== LEAK SUMMARY:
==59142==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==59142==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==59142==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==59142==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==59142==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==59142==
==59142== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==59142== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

This clearly demonstrates that there is a memory leak.

Comment: Please don't post non answers as answers.

Comment: How is this not an answer? Infact it gave a detailed description of what exactly happened!

Comment: @VishalSharma: I've added a final sentence which helps a bit.